# Why is the standard reduction potential of an anode negative in a galvanic cell?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrons

It makes not intuitive sense to me why something can have a negative voltage , I understand the concept of voltage drop , but voltage is not being dropped in the anode so why would it be negative ?

Comment: Sign of potential doesn't have any meaning, since zero is arbitrary anyway.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16785/positive-or-negative-anode-cathode-in-electrolytic-galvanic-cell

Answer (score 0):

The anode is where the oxidation takes place, by definition, so the reduction potential must be more negative (or at least less positive) than the reduction potential at the cathode.

But, there is no guarantee that the reduction potential at the anode is negative.