Does the cathode always attain a positive charge or is it just a convention?
Suppose I have a galvanic cell composed of two half cells, one containing Zinc electrode dipped in an electrolytic solution (say of ZnSO4) while the another one having Lithium electrode dipped in another electrolytic solution (say Li2SO4) (Both connected via a conducting wire and a salt bridge).
When the half cell containing zinc electrode is isolated, it is observed that at the electrode-solution/electrolyte interface zinc atom present on electrode shows a tendency to get dissolved in the electrolytic solution, leaving behind two electrons which get accumulated on the zinc electrode.
As time progresses, the reaction starts to progress backwards also. At equilibrium, it is observed that due to greater initial tendency of zinc atoms to get dissolved in the solution, the electrode accumulates an overall negative charge.
When this zinc electrode is connected to the lithium electrode, which also have a tendency (though higher than that of zinc) to get oxidised in it's isolated phase and thus also accumulate a negative charge on itself, which is greater than that present on zinc electrode, it is observed that a potential difference is generated between the zinc terminal end and lithium terminal end. However due to higher potential at lithium electrode, electrons flow from lithium electrode to zinc electrode. Thus the zinc electrode acts as a cathode while lithium electrode acts as an anode.
Usually cathode is represented by a positive sign in the case of galvanic cell. In this case, zinc has accumulated a negative charge. However since zinc established equilibrium between its electrolytic and electrode phase, the excess electrons arriving at cathode would initiate the conversion of zinc ions to zinc solid, i.e. reduction at cathode.So is the positive sign on Anode just a convention or Have I misinterpreted something here??

Lithium cannot be dipped in an aqueous solution, because this metal reacts with water. Furthermore, in a cell zinc-lithium, zinc has not a tendency to be dissolved

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16785/positive-or-negative-anode-cathode-in-electrolytic-galvanic-cell

The chemistry is inappropriate in acidic aqueous solution H+ will be reduced before Zn++. Oxidation happens at the anode reduction at the cathode electron flow is from negative to positive. In a galvanic cell electrons flow from anode to cathode so the anode is negative. The cathode is positive but it is negative with respect to the solution ions.

Being a cathode or anode is not directly related to the charge or potential of the electrode, but to direction of the electron transfer in closed circuits. (or the direction that would occur if the circuit got closed)
Anodes take electrons away from electrolyte, causing oxidation, cathodes do the opposite.
Marking the cell contacts (+) and (-) is misleading.

It does not mean the contact(+) has positive potential and the contaxt (-) has negative one.
It does not mean the respective contacts have positive/negative potentials wrt the reference SHE electrode either.
It just means the (+) contact has higher(=more positive) potential than the (-) contact.


If we take as the example the classical Daniell cell,
$$\ce{Zn|ZnSO4||CuSO4|Cu}$$
then the zinc electrode has lower potential than the copper electrode.
But

when used as a galvanic cell, zinc electrode is the anode (oxidation), the copper electrode is the cathode(reduction).
when used as an electrolytic cell, charging it, than zinc electrode is the cathode(reduction), the copper electrode is the anode(oxidation).

Note that potentials of electrodes are not absolute potentials, but relative potentials related to the standard hydrogen electrode (SHE).
SHE has then the absolute electrode potential $\pu{+4.44 \pm 0.02 V}$ referring to the conventional zero potential of free electron in vacuum.
